# BigQuery view not allowing to add policy tag to column

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery shows option to add policy tag to Table by editing schema. Unable to do the same for BigQuery view.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.
Seems like the policy tags of the view remain the same as the table from which it is derived.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#work_for_views